# create a object from array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have two list of arrays with country code and currencies in order, but I need to know how to combine and form  a object in the following format.

```
var cn =["AL","DZ","AS","AD","AO","AI","AG","AR","AM","AW","AU"];
var ccy = ["ALL","DZD","USD","EUR","AOA","XCD","XCD","ARS","AMD","AWG","AUD"];
```

Expected Output:

```
country:[
{
  "code": "AL",
  "currency": ["ALL"]
},
{
  "code": "DZ",
  "currency": ["DZD"]
}...
...
{
  "code": "AU",
  "currency": ["AUD"]
}
]
```

Comment: Where is the rule for matching `code` and `currency`? Do they just match 1 on 1?

Comment: @zynkn thanks for reply, yes they match 1 on 1

Comment: Use [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods) methods. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ***map*** and use ***index*** to access corresponding value from second array

```js
var cn =["AL","DZ","AS","AD","AO","AI","AG","AR","AM","AW","AU"];
var ccy = ["ALL","DZD","USD","EUR","AOA","XCD","XCD","ARS","AMD","AWG","AUD"];

let final = cn.map((code,index)=>{
  let currency = ccy[index]
  return {code, currency: [currency]}
})

console.log(final)
```

Comment: @Quirimmo If you don't agree with code in someone's answer, don't edit it to change the code; instead, write your own answer.

Comment: @tyler actually I just changed syntactic sugar, and I thought the changes were suggested and he had to approve them. Sorry guys revert t back

Comment: @quirimmo No worries. Generally a better idea is to suggest/explain the edits in a comment instead :) Also, changing `let` to `const` is **not** "syntactic sugar"; it's a completely different statement, despite the implications not being present in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to map over one of the two arrays, and use the current index to retrieve the corresponding value in the other array. During each iteration, return the object you want to create:

```
cc.map((code, index) => ({ code: code, currency: ccy[index]}));
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach might be to iterate the code array using a lambda with an index, then push each JSON object in each iteration.

```js
var cn =["AL","DZ","AS","AD","AO","AI","AG","AR","AM","AW","AU"];
var ccy = ["ALL","DZD","USD","EUR","AOA","XCD","XCD","ARS","AMD","AWG","AUD"];
var country = [];

cn.forEach(function (value, i) {
    country.push({code: value, currency: ccy[i]});
});

console.log(country);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var cn =["AL","DZ","AS","AD","AO","AI","AG","AR","AM","AW","AU"];
var ccy = ["ALL","DZD","USD","EUR","AOA","XCD","XCD","ARS","AMD","AWG","AUD"];
var country = [];
for (let i = 0; i < cn.length; i++) {
    country.push({ code: cn[i], currency: ccy[i] });    
}
```

could do the work

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for this:

```js
var cn =["AL","DZ","AS","AD","AO","AI","AG","AR","AM","AW","AU"];
var ccy = ["ALL","DZD","USD","EUR","AOA","XCD","XCD","ARS","AMD","AWG","AUD"];
var result = cn.map((code, idx) => ({ code, cn: [ccy[idx]]}));

console.log(result);
```